# "Method \"POST\" not allowed." Django REST

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am new to django rest framework. I have an api to get corresponding token for each user. The method defined to access token is

```
class ObtainAuthToken(APIView):

def post(self, request):
    user = authenticate(
        username=request.data['username'], password=request.data['password'])
    if user:
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({'token': token.key, 'user': UserSerializer(user).data})
    return Response('Invalid username or password', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and in urls.py i have

```
url(r'^login/$',ObtainAuthToken, name='login')
```

But while logging in a user, i am getting the response as

```
{
"detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."
}
```

Where did i went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - I see that you used the `django-rest-auth` tag. Are you actually using rest auth? If not - you should definitely consider doing it as it provides a ton of auth functionality out of the box.

As to your question, you forgot to call `as_view()` on `ObtainAuthToken` in your url conf. Change it like so and tell me if it works:

```
url(r'^login/$', ObtainAuthToken.as_view(), name='login')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong indentation in your code. The post method needs to be inside the `ObtainAuthToken(APIView)` class. Right now is defined as a standalone function.